# Authorization has been denied when creating ASP.NET Web API with API Key validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to authorize my web api with a key, but it always says "Authorization has been denied for this request." The following is the last code that I tried.

This is the Delegating handler class:

```
// Message Handler class
public class APIKeyFilter: DelegatingHandler
    {
        // Default API Key
        private const string APIKEY = "b018a9c5105d427127e";
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var query = request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();
            string key = query["key"];
            if (APIKEY!=key)
            {
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
                var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
                tsc.SetResult(response);
                return tsc.Task;
            }
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }


    }
```

This is the global class:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new Filter.APIKeyFilter());
        }
    }
```

This is my api controller:

```
    [Authorize]
    public class CategoriesController : ApiController
    {
        private WebAPI2Context db = new WebAPI2Context();

        // GET: api/Categories
        public IQueryable<Category> GetCategories()
        {
            return db.Categories;
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to fix this? I try to google it, all results I found not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing too obvious wrong although don't confuse filters with handlers.

It might be that you are trying to make calls to the Web API controller from a website running in another process, on a different port. Could be caused by Possible issue 1, 2 or both below.

**Possible reason 1**

Perhaps this is a CORS issue. Hard to tell without more info from response. Try adding this to your Global:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableCors(cors);
```

and for pre-fight checks I'd add the following under the `If` you have in your custom handler:

```
if (request.Headers.Contains("Origin") && request.Method.Method == "OPTIONS")
            {
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
                response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
                response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
                //Worked before for deletes but CORS came back out of blue for deletes so changed * for DELETE and content doing al CRUD at the moment..
                response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, GET");
            }
```

If it is this you'll all need to install the NuGet: Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

**Possible reason 2**

You will also need to ensure `machineKey` is set the same the config files for both.

Follow the instructions in the following URL to match up the settings between the applications and you should be fine:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx